# Xubuntu apt-get Errors

Tags: 14.04, apt, xubuntu, dpkg, lock

when i try to use the command apt-get update these errors appear:

E: No se pudo abrir el fichero de bloqueo «/var/lib/apt/lists/lock» - open (13: Permiso denegado)

E: No se pudo bloquear el directorio /var/lib/apt/lists/

E: No se pudo abrir el fichero de bloqueo «/var/lib/dpkg/lock» - open (13: Permiso denegado)

E: No se encontró un archivo de réplica «/var/lib/dpkg/»

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

issue the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You will be prompted for your password.

The error you are getting is a 'perpission denied' error. That means you don't have the right to do something. Typing sudo (comes from super user do) before a command executes it as the Super User. This user has permission to do everything, and because of that, you should use it with caution.

Comment: originally the error was caused with sudo typed... I did a memscan yesterday and today it worked normally